# maven, fix compile order modules

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module project.

Project contain some jar modules, one war module, one ear module. War depends on jars, pom.xml of ear module contain dependencies for all other modules - ear file deployed in container.

Every time I make new ear file I need first compile all other modules (and remember right order of compilation). I'm tired of this.

I know about parent module. http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html
But it seems not a good solution for me.

Does I have any other solution to fix compile order modules?

Comment: Why is the parent module not a good solution?

Comment: because in this case I need to specify parent module in each pom. But some jars may be used in other projects or in the same project to make another ear

Comment: Modules with a parent project can still be built independently.

Comment: mmm. ok. I specify parent module in each pom. If I need another ear I compile jar modules by myself? It's a solution, but not so good (( Maven really doesn't offer another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the modules are dependent in a way that they must be built together, there are two ways you could handle this.

1. Use a parent pom (they were designed to address this situation)
2. Use an external build script to build the dependencies before building the main project